# When the goals were scored (range)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a mysql query that will show when the teams score their goals during the matches. I have a table that is setup like this: clubid(int) and minute(tinyint). This what I want to achieve:

Minute 1-15 31 goals

Minute 16-30    43 goals

Minute 31-45    36 goals

Minute 46-60    51 goals

Minute 61-75    48 goals

Minute 76-90    52 goals

First I would like to do it for every team in the league and then for each team separate. This is my attempt of the query for the whole league, but unfortunaly it doesn´t work.

```
  SELECT *,count(minute) as summary 
  CASE WHEN minute >= 1  AND minute <= 15 THEN  '1-15'
       WHEN minute >= 16 AND minute <= 30 THEN '16-30' 
       WHEN minute >= 31 AND minute <= 45 THEN '31-45' 
       WHEN minute >= 46 AND minute <= 60 THEN '46-60' 
       WHEN minute >= 61 AND minute <= 75 THEN '61-75'
       WHEN minute >= 76 AND minute <= 90 THEN '76-90'
       WHEN minute > 90  AND THEN 90+
       ELSE 'no goals' END as range          
  FROM teamgoals 
  ORDER BY range asc
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: try `GROUP BY range` or add your data into sqlFiddle.com

Comment: For ranges during which no goals are scored, there will be no result. Have you thought about how you'd want to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2b18e/8/0)

```
SELECT IFNULL(T1.summary,0) as summary,
       rangeDescription.`range`
  FROM (      SELECT '1-15' as `range`, 1 as rowOrder
        UNION SELECT '16-30'        , 2
        UNION SELECT '31-45'        , 3
        UNION SELECT '46-60'        , 4
        UNION SELECT '61-75'        , 5
        UNION SELECT '76-90'        , 6
        UNION SELECT '90+'          , 7
        )rangeDescription
  LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT count(minute) as summary, 
          CASE WHEN minute >= 1  AND minute <= 15 THEN  '1-15'
               WHEN minute >= 16 AND minute <= 30 THEN '16-30' 
               WHEN minute >= 31 AND minute <= 45 THEN '31-45' 
               WHEN minute >= 46 AND minute <= 60 THEN '46-60' 
               WHEN minute >= 61 AND minute <= 75 THEN '61-75'
               WHEN minute >= 76 AND minute <= 90 THEN '76-90'
               WHEN minute > 90   THEN '90+'
               ELSE 'no goals' 
          END as `range` 
        FROM
        teamgoals
        WHERE clubId = 1
         GROUP BY `range`
        )T1
   ON rangeDescription.`range` = T1.`range`
ORDER BY rangeDescription.rowOrder asc
```

Comment: @Strawberry A goal scored within the first minute would be included in 1-15, wouldn't it? You can't score a goal in the 0th minute. Similarly a goal scored at 89 mins and 30 secs is scored in the 90th minute.

Comment: Doh! I better have some coffee

Comment: Thanks Tin Tran for giving the solution to my problem.